# Can we tune any of the parameters on testing data, including any parameters learned by preprocessing?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, hyperparameters, train-test-split

I want to normalize the data using `StandardScaler` function.

But I have doubts about how this should be done.

1. One way to do this is like as follows:

```
    scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
    X = scaler.transform(X)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

2. And the other case is like this:

```
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
    X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

I read somewhere that we should never tune any of our parameters on testing data, including any parameters learned by preprocessing (scale, bias).

According to this fact, is only the second case correct?
I'm a little confused.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: That said, you should put aside your test data in the very beginning of the process and act as if they were not available, until the final use of them just to test your model.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with second case yes.

Assume that you train your model and on a later moment you use it on novel data, the accuracy you would expect is similar to the one you achieved on the validation (actually on the test set but for sake of simplicity..).
What will happen is that some informations from your validation have leaked into your model (aka the bias and mean during the preprocessing) and it may perform better on validation thanks to this.